# How can I get the mean by groups in a list in R

Tags: r, list, group-by, mean

I have a list like this:

| Years | sallary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 |
| 12 | 4343 |
| 25 | 1341 |
| 23 | 12 |
| 15 | 325 |
| 2 | 574 |
| 4 | 5473 |
| 8 | 347 |
| 30 | 352 |
| 29 | 237 |
| 3 | 734 |
| 10 | 2469 |
| 11 | 1239 |
| 5 | 2456 |
| 20 | 231 |
| 6 | 9381 |
| 28 | 1284 |
| 13 | 1295 |
| 9 | 129 |
| 7 | 931 |
| 19 | 1293 |
| 27 | 1239 |
| 14 | 124 |
| 24 | 512 |
| 18 | 912 |
| 26 | 8321 |
| 17 | 12383 |
| 22 | 419 |
| 16 | 129 |
| more than 30 years | 12394 |
| 21 | 1239 |

Sorry for the huge list but I my list is even bigger and I have to make sure no one gives me the list hard-coded.
What I want is a list with the mean of grouped years.

```
group1 <- c("less than 1 year", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
group2 <- c("6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
...
```

```
| Years | sallary | 
|:---- |:------:| 
| group1  | e.g. 1295    | 
| group2  | e.g. 12012   | 
| group3  | e.g. 8521    | 
| group4  | e.g. 2491    | 
| group5  | e.g. 12349   | 
| group6  | e.g. 1299    | 

I amm sorry for this list but otherwise it gives me an error if I do not put the table inside the code block... But that is the list I want.
```

Other answers doesn't help, because they calculate their means by same rows. But I have a strings.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We replace the 'Years' based on the group vectors.  Get all the 'group' vectors into a `list` with `mget`, convert the `list` to two-column `data.frame` (`stack`), then do a join with the original data, replace the 'Years' column with the 'value', use that as grouping column and `summarise` the 'sallary' column

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- stack(mget(ls(pattern = '^group\\d+$')))[2:1]
names(df2)[2] <- 'Years'
df1 %>% 
     left_join(df2, by = 'Years') %>%
     group_by(Years = ind) %>%
     summarise(sallary = mean(sallary, na.rm = TRUE))
```